# how to get vlc logs?

Tags: logging, vlc, rtsp, rtsp-client

I am trying to run rtsp url from the VLC player.  But an error appears, and "see logs for details" comes up in a dialog box.

How can I enable logs in VLC?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I found the following command to run from command line:

```
vlc.exe --extraintf=http:logger --verbose=2 --file-logging --logfile=vlc-log.txt
```

Comment: IMHO is better to increase the verbosity level than change the command for execute the program

Comment: It depends. I needed to save logs to a file so I can post on pastebin.com and then link that on a forum topic regarding my problem. Different needs and all.

Comment: For me (windows) this worked better than the GUI Messages window because it opens up a console, which displays helpful stdout messages from sublibraries that don't show up in the Messages window, even with verbosity set to 2...

Comment: this log file is saved in c://Users/<yourUser>

Comment: when i run this command in cmd it says vlc.exe is not recognized as a command

Comment: @sukhvir, you need to run the command from where VLC is installed down to the folder where the vlc.exe file is located, eg `C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC>`

Answer (score 87):

Or you can use the more obvious solution, right in the GUI: Tools -> Messages (set verbosity to 2)...

Comment: I cannot see any such option in Mac using VLC 2.2.1

Comment: @PraveshJain It's there. Or just press ⌘+Shift+m (http://www.cheatography.com/shaunumb/cheat-sheets/vlc-windows-and-os-x/)

Comment: It seems to be under Window->Messages on a current macOS build. I couldn't see how to change the verbosity though.

Comment: Not very helpful when the error is telling you to check the log for details....

Comment: just a caveat - you might need to try the failing procedure again when the messages window is already visible. At least for me, otherwise it was empty, regardless of the verbosity