# Accessing RTSP IP Camera using my public IP authentication issue

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, rtsp, ip-camera

I am using VLC to try to connect to my IP camera (reolink):

When I use this:

rtsp://admin:admin@local_ip_address

It works and connects fine. However when I use this:

rtsp://admin:admin@public_ip_address

It brings up the authentication box and asks for my username and password again - seems like its wrong. So it is connecting to it because if i change the public_ip_address to a random one, it cant find it. So for some reason the authentication fails when I try access via the public_ip_address.

If i go to public_ip_address in my browser, i connect fine to the camera.

Does anyone know why this authentication fails?

Comment: You need to check the logs

Comment: where does one find the logs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303017/how-to-get-vlc-logs/9422315#9422315